# Poisson process - calculating expected number of events within a uniform distribution

Tags: probability

Struggling to wrap my head around this problem.

- (a) Find the expected number of passengers who wait for 1 unit of time or less.
- b) Find P ( at least three who wait more than 1 unit of time).

I believe I have to find the joint distribution of the passenger arrival and train departure. But possibly the probability of a passenger having to wait 1 second or less? A bit lost..

Thanks!

Comment: Can you do it for one train?

Comment: Can I specifically? No. I understand that, in addition to the first train, I will have to accommodate for the expected number of passengers that will wait a second or less for the second train at time 5. But I'm having difficult even beginning the problem.

Comment: I mean, if there is just one train at 5pm, can you find the expected number of passengers who wait 1 minute or less?

Comment: What trains? What passengers?

Comment: @DilipSarwate: see edits.